# Effectivly creating a tabbed website with RadTabStrip

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, telerik

I have an ASP.NET web application that I am making and I am thinking of making it a tabbed interface using Telerik's RadTabStrip. I am trying to figure out the best way to approach this though.  I would need about 10 tabs because I have about 10 different main areas of my application. My question is how is the best way to integrate the content into the tabs. All of the simple examples I've seen create RadViews with imbedded HTML/ASP.NET content. The problem with this approach is that, with 10 tabs, it would make my main ASPX file really really big and it would be kind of clumsy to work with, having to integrate all 10 pages into one page. Is there a better or more accepted way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you have several possibilities:

- Use one RadTabStrip and several RadView controls. Put the content for each tab into a separate user control (*.ascx). Then you only have to include the user controls in your main aspx page.
- Use a master page and put the RadTabStrip on it. Create a separate page for each area of your application (each using the same master page). Use the RadTab's NavigateUrl property to navigate to the corresponding page (as shown in [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/applicationscenarios/sitenavigation/defaultcs.aspx)).
- there are certainly other possibilities...